# Parsing a JSON document that contains HTML in r

Tags: r, rvest, jsonlite

If I query my target link as follows:

```
library(jsonlite)
link <- "https://www.forest-trends.org/wp-content/themes/foresttrends/map_tools/project_fetch_single.php?pid=1"
df <- fromJSON(link)
```

I get a JSON list with one element: `df$html`. I would like to parse this HTML using `rvest` in order to access tags like `psize` and `pstatus`. But the double backslashes `\\` seem to stop me. Any idea how to formulate my `rvest` query correctly? I'm thinking of something like:

```
df$html %>% html_node(xpath = '//div[contains(@class, \"psize\")]') %>% html_text()
```

Comment: I'm quite a beginner to that, but are you sure it's JSON?

Comment: Good point. I'm not entirely sure - I think it's a list with one element that has some weird encoding I dont understand.

Comment: This `read_html(df$html) |> html_element(xpath = '//div[contains(@class, "psize")]') |> html_text()` works for me (output: `[1] "Size: 85000 ha"`)? What do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining a few different functions, you can arrive to that. This is not suppose to be a 100% correct answer, but it can give some ideas about how to format the string.

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)

split <- read_html(link) %>% 
  html_node(xpath='/html/body/div') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  strsplit(., split = "\\\\n|\\\\t")

split <- split[[1]][!is.na(split[[1]]) & split[[1]] != ""]
data.frame(col1 = split[1:5]) %>% 
  separate(col = col1, into = c("col1", "col2"), sep = ": ", extra = "drop")

          col1                                                             col2
1          Size                                                         85000 ha
2        Status                                                   In development
3   Description                              REDD project in Madre de Dios, Peru
4     Objective Carbon sequestration or avoided, Carbon sequestration or avoided
5 Interventions                                   Afforestation or reforestation
```